# Missing HttpContext.Items for some actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Background:

MVC3 intranet application using windows authentication. After windows authentication completes, a HttpModule looks up the user's network id from an HR database and returns the user's employee information and sets it in `HttpContext.Items`.  I have a base controller that looks for this information and sets a ViewBag property by overriding OnActionExecuting.

My question is that this `HttpContext.Items["UserInfo"]` information only seems to be available on Home/Index only and not available when I click to Home/About or Home/Help although HomeController inherits BaseController. Can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
        {          
            if (this.HttpContext.Items["UserInfo"] != null)
            {
                UserInfo User = (UserInfo)this.HttpContext.Items["UserInfo"];
                ViewBag.CurrentUser = User;
            }            

            base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Items` is per request only; it is not retained when you redirect to another view or even post back within the current view.  So you need to use `Session` or something else to persist it.